# Bluebird Promise.map with a nested promise not "finishing"

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm still trying to figure out proper promise patterns in bluebird, and I'm having trouble with this particular structure.

```
function mainFunction() {
    Promise.map(arrayValues, function(value) {

        return function1(value)
            .then(function(resp1) {
                return function2(resp1);
            })
            .then(function(resp2) {
                return function3 (resp2);
            })
    })
    .then(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
        throw e;
    });
}
```

I'm never getting any output to the final console.log(resp), which makes me think that I'm returning the promise incorrectly. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
If I add a

```
 .then(function(resp) {
     console.log(resp);
 })
```

To the response of function3, it prints just fine. However that response never seems to get returned out of the Map function and no catch block is ever tripped..

---

Edit 3:

I think I figured it out. There was a messy resolve/reject block I had in my code that I didn't think completely through and wasn't returning a Promise properly, keeping the Promise.map hung.

I guess this is a good a place as any to figure out how to properly handle this.

I have this code here that makes a http request to a server and than parses the body of the HTML along multiple URLs like so:

```
Promise.map(arrayURLs, function(url) {
    function requestHTML(url) {
        console.log('HTTP GET : ' + url);

        return request.getAsync({
            'url': url
        })
        .then(function(html) {
            console.log('HTTP RESP: ' + url);
            return html[0].body;
        })
        .error(function() {
            return Promise.reject();
            console.log('HTTP Err: ' + url);
        });
    }
})
```

The idea behind this is that I do some work on the body of the HTML that this returns. However, if the HTTP request fails, no biggie, I just want to ignore it and have the rest of the HTTP requests go through. I want to stop the propagation of the error here because the rest of the code will fail if it gets a null html body, and its simple to handle this error here.

What is the best way to gracefully handle the case of a null return body so that the `Promise.map` still works as intended?

Comment: you are missing an opening parens on line `return function3 resp2);`

Comment: I fixed it, but that's not the issue. I'm not getting any errors or exceptions, the program just stops and never prints anything.

Comment: And the `.catch` block is not called? I would add a `console.log` into each `then` to determine where the code _breaks_.

Comment: I replicated you code and set `function1` to `function getPromise(s) {
 return new Promise( function(resolve) {
        setTimeout( function() { resolve('done!'); } , s);
  });
}` and everything resolved fine.  Are you sure your `function1`'s promise is getting resolved? (I set `arrayValues` to `var arrayValues = [1,2,3,4];`)

Comment: Added an edit to the OP to explain what happens with the console.log

Comment: Completely abstract questions like this with no real code are tough for us to help you debug because we don't know how you're trying to use this, what you're really trying to accomplish or where in the abstraction you  might be making a mistake.  Real code with a real problem will likely get you much more useful help.

Comment: Also, your function in the `Promise.map()` can just be `return function1(value).then(function2).then(function3);`.  You don't need the anonymous wrappers.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/up2pm483/

Comment: Added a third edit with what I figured out.

Comment: In reply to your third edit (which is really a new question and should be posted as such), if you get an error but want everything else to continue, why not just return an empty string for the body rather than returning a rejected promise.

Comment: @t.neise: I'm trying to learn about Promises; I write about "And the .catch block is not called?" (Sep 16 at 15:05). Had you written that to me, I wouldn't have known how to check whether the .catch block is called. Might you share a bit more?